# Fitting a question to the scope: Counting Systems

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This question was asked yesterday

[Developing Counting Systems](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29471/developing-counting-systems)

It was voted off-topic: not about worldbuilding. And some comment even suggest to move it to Math.SE. One other user took it to him to [edit the question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12820) to try to fit the scope. That edit got accepted (2 to 1... that 1 being me), and a reopen vote went through (5 to 2).

Apart from introducing a much too broad question, the edit changes the focus of the question, IMO. So the OP may get answers which are not relevant to what s/he was asking/interested in.

My philosophy would be to suggest the OP to make a similar edit, but not do it ourselves. Unless, maybe, a reasonable amount of time has passed since the suggestion. Of course, the OP may roll back, but that might invalidate some of the answers given in between.

Am I too strict? Or what should we do in similar case?

Comment: Also note that the only answer (which was accepted) does not really fit the new question.

Comment: Ironically in this case it looks like a duplicate to me...